# Stored procedure into PDF for billing

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, billing

I am looking for the best way to create a PDF from the results of my stored procedure. It will be used for billing to our customers.

What are your recommendations?

If it looks and feel professional it would be a big plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reporting Services which comes with SQL Server.

You can create a report that will use the output of your stored procedure to output a professional looking statement.

You could implement a subscription in Reporting Services that can easily generate 1 PDF per customer and place everything in a file folder (or email individual PDFs).

Here's an [introduction](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/222/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/)